# newbie in javascript closure, and the closure test's result is unexpect

Tags: javascript, closures

newbie in javascript closure

i follow a example from internet, and try to change some of it

i think it should give me 16,17,18,19

but the result was unexpect

here is my code. 
i do not know why i first call bar2(10),it alert 17, does it should give me 18?

---

```
function foo(x) {
    var tmp = 3;
    return function (y) {
        alert(x + y + (++tmp));
    }
}
var bar = foo(2); 
bar(10);//alert16
bar(10);//alert17
var bar2 =  foo(3);
bar2(10);//alert17
bar2(10);//alert18
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result 17 is correct.

Each call to `foo` produces a *new* function with a *new* closed-over variable `tmp`.

Perhaps you thought the second call to `foo` uses the same `tmp` as in the first call?  It doesn't.  That is why you get 17:  3 + 10 + 4.

Comment: so it's same as "var bar2 = new foo(3)" ?

Comment: No, the operator `new` in JavaScript does a lot behind the scenes: it creates a new object, calls the function in a context where `this` refers to the new object, sets the prototype of the new object to the value of `foo.prototype`, and will implicitly return the new object under certain conditions.  None of which applies to your question.  All that happens when you say `var bar2 = foo(3)` is that you call the function `foo`.  But each time you call `foo` it gets its own copies of its local variables (of which `tmp` is one).  That happens _even without closures_.

Answer (score 2):

Because `tmp` is a variable local to the function you return from `foo` -- that means when you call `foo` for the second time, it gets reset to 3.  3 + (3+1) + 10 = 17.

Answer (score 0):

1. bar(y) = n = x + y + tmp
2. bar(10) = 16 = 2 + 10 + 4
3. bar(10) = 17 = 2 + 10 + 5
4. bar2(10) = 17 = 3 + 10 + 4
5. bar2(10) = 18 = 3 + 10 + 5